# Does USA have free, online legal databases in the same format as AustLII, BAILII, CanLII, CommonLII?

Tags: reference-request

I am acclimatized to the same formats of [AustLII](https://www.austlii.edu.au),  [BAILII](https://www.bailii.org), [CanLII](https://www.canlii.org/en), [CommonLII](http://www.commonlii.org), [HKLII](https://www.hklii.hk/), [NZLII](http://www.nzlii.org), etc... These are all so user-friendly!

##### Does USA have anything analogous to the aforementioned *FREE, ONLINE* LII's? Like USLII?

I am NOT asking about [Cornell Law School's LII, FindLaw, Justia, etc...](https://www.law.gmu.edu/library/freelegalresearch) because these are designed in different formats.